# Variable must be inialized

Tags: java

I'm currently creating a program in Java similar to below: It asking for the variable AC to be initialized.

```
double AC;
System.out.println("Please choose A or B")

If(Condition to see if it A)
{
AC = 1
}
else if(Condition to see if it B)
{
AC = 2
}
else 
{
System.out.println("Please Enter a valid choice!")
}

double ab = AC * 2
```

This would be give an error of " The variable AC must be initialized" The reason it causing this is because if the user don't choose A or B, there would be no AC to be use in double ab. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Please don't give us pseudo-code, it's hard to know which error is important for you.

Answer (score 1):

That's what it says : you must ensure `AC` is initialized before you use it.

Your problem is that `AC` has no value if you fall in the last `else`.

You might give it a default value :

```
double AC = 33.2; // or Double.NaN if you prefer
System.out.println("Please choose A or B")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Local variables and primitives should be initialized before use because you would know what to expect from the values

Hence you have to initialize the value of the variables such `AC = <<any value>>;`

Please consider below **example**

```
int a;  // Valid
int b;
println("a=" + b);  // Not valid since b's value has never been assigned
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to stop the code after it run "Please enter a valid choice" Thanks

Comment: @user1906857 better you give something useful than any pseudo code.

Comment: If you are using loop then you can break the loop or if you are using method then you can return from method or throw an `IllegalArgumentException` .

Answer (score 0):

in Java 7 you can use switch with string

```
    switch (choose) {
    case "A":
        AC = 1;
        break;

    case "B":
        AC = 2;
        break;

    default:
        AC = -1;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

- The `else` clause which is executed only requests a valid number be used.  Even if this would compile, the flow through the program would be incorrect due to the value never being re-established to a valid value; that is to say, you don't loop through to check for an answer again.
- The `else` clause makes no attempt to assign a value to `AC`, which is one of the places the compiler looks to see if `AC` is assigned; there's no guarantee that either of the other two code paths will be followed, but the `else` is *always* followed.  It can't see it there, so you get the "variable might not have been initialized" error.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to initialize AC since it's possible neither option of the "if" would. Just do

```
double AC = -1;
```

or some dummy value.

Comment: You're confusing potential readers of the question and its answers by confusing OP's variables `AC` and `ab`.

Comment: Thanks you for the two answer. Is there a way to stop  the code after it print "Please enter a valid choice" and not continue to the double ab? Thanks